# Is there a way to get the TelephonyCallback.SignalStrengthsListener to work when the screen is off?

Tags: signal-strength

Is is possible to get the TelephonyCallback.SignalStrengthsListener (Api 31) to work when the screen is off? I register telephonyCallback which has in foreground service's onCreate method, CellInfoListener works when the screen is off but SignalStrengthsListener does not. Battery optimization is turned off for the app. Wakelock is applied in the foreground service.

Foreground service, wakelock, turn off battery optimization